# How to search for which int is in which slot of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int arr[6]={1,8,24,43,15,20};
int input;
bool exists = find(begin(arr), end(arr), input) != end(arr);




cout << "Enter a number : " << endl;
cin >> input;
if (input==1) {
cout << "It is indeed in the array." << endl;
}
else {
cout << "Nope, try again." << endl;
}
}
```

I want to find a way to make it more specific where a user can input a number and it will be able to find which slot of the array it is in. For example:

int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5}; User inputs: 4,. Value 4 is in slot 4. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-index-of-a-given-element-in-a-vector-in-cpp/)

Comment: Your `input` variable is not initialized before the `find` call.

Comment: You may want to move your `find` function call to *after* the `input` variable is input from the User.

Comment: what you mean by `slot`? do you want to find an element in the array if it does exists?

Comment: Please, at least build you code before ask about it!

Answer (score 1):

`std::find` returns iterator to the element (if found). Instead of simply comparing it with `end`, you can use that iterator to get the index. Index of an element in a range is same as the distance of the element from the beginning of the range. As such, simply calculate the distance from `begin` to the found iterator. There is a standard function to calculate that distance. Its name is `std::distance`.

Note that indices in C++ language (and in most programming in general) are 0 based, so you need to add 1 to the index to get the corresponding "slot" as you've specified.

---

P.S. As Thomas Matthews points out, your example program is broken. You should fix that before attempting to calculate the slot.

Comment: FYI, there seems to be an issue with the statement order.  The `find` is called before the `input` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::find` to get an iterator to target item and then use `std::distance` to compute its zero-based index! and resolve yours errors! call `std::find` after `cin` and add proper `return` to `main`!

Try

```
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int arr[6] = { 1,8,24,43,15,20 };

    int input;
    cout << "Enter a number : " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    auto iter = find(begin(arr), end(arr), input);
    if (iter != end(arr))
    {
        cout << "Slot is ." << distance(begin(arr), iter) + 1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Nope, try again." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a `linear search` also!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[6]={1,8,24,43,15,20};
    int input, slot = -1;
    cout << "Enter a number : " << endl;
    cin>>input;

    bool flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        if(input == arr[i]){
            slot = i + 1;
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(flag){
        cout << "It is indeed in the array. Slot: " << slot << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Nope, try again." << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::find` *is* linear search though.

Comment: yes it is. I just wanted show the OP how it works! Thank you :)